# Should I create a context for something that is mostly useCallback or simply create a hook?

Tags: reactjs

I'm just doing a bit of refactoring and I was wondering if I have a bunch of useCallback calls that I want to group together, is it better do it as a simple hook that I would reuse in a few places?

The result would be

```
interface IUtils {
  something(req: Something) : Result;
  somethingElse(req: SomethingElse) : Result;
  // etc...
}
```

So a plain hooks example would be:

```
export function useUtils() : IUtils {
  // there's more but basically for this example I am just using one.
  // to narrow the focus down, the `use` methods on this 
  // block are mostly getting data from existing contexts
  // and they themselves do not have any `useEffect` 
  const authenticatedClient = useAuthenticatedClient();  

  // this is a method that takes some of the common context stuff like client
  // or userProfile etc from above and provides a simpler API for 
  // the hook users so they don't have to manually create those calls anymore
  const something = useCallback((req:SomethingRequest)=> doSomething(authenticatedClient), [authenticatedClient]
  // there are a few of the above too.
  return {
    something 
  }
}
```

The other option was to create a context similar to the above

```
const UtilsContext = createContext<IUtils>({ something: noop });
export UtilsProvider({children}:PropsWithChildren<{}>) : JSX.Element {

  const authenticatedClient = useAuthenticatedClient();  

  const something = useCallback((req:SomethingRequest)=> doSomething(authenticatedClient), [authenticatedClient]

  const contextValue = useMemo({something}, [something]);
  
  return <UtilsContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</UtilsContext.Provider>
}
```

The performance difference between the two approaches are not really visible (since I can only test it in the device) even on the debugger and I am not sure how to even set it up on set up on jsben.ch.

Having it as just a simple hook is easier I find because I don't have to deal with adding yet another component to the tree, but even if I use it in a number of places I don't see any visible improvement but the devices could be so fast that it's moot.  But what's the best practice in this situation?

Comment: It entirely depends on what `useAuthenticatedClient` is doing.

Comment: I see, most of the uses are just getting data from other contexts.  So no heavy lifting.  Which is likely why I don't see anything.

Comment: So basically the answer would be something like use a context if the dependencies are expensive or have side effects.  But if not the no-context approach would be better.